# how do i get websocket data from client to my flask app route?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

i'm developing my first face recognition project. i'm using `mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` for accesing client webcam and send the webcam stream to flask app with websocket. i just receive the webcam stream from my socket route in my server, but i don't how to get those data to my flask app route. i've been searching any related answer but none of them solved my problem.

how do i get webcam stream from websocket to my flask app route ? i would appreciate any answer, i really need it. thank you !

JavaScript

```
var socket = io('https://0.0.0.0:8000');

socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connected !', socket.connected);
});


function capture() {
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 200;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200,200);  
  var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

  return data;
};

var FPS = 22

setInterval(()=> {
    var imgData = capture();

    socket.emit('image', imgData);

}, 1000/FPS);
```

flask app

```
@socketio.on('image')
def image(data_image):
    encoded_image = data_image.split(",")[1]

    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded_image)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(decoded, np.uint8), -1)#this is the thing that 
                                                             #i want to use in my below flask route



@app.route('/greet', methods = ['GET'])
def tes():
    return render_template('greetings.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your socket.emit need to be nested inside socket.on function?
I would suggest you try to change your JavaScript code like this.

```
var socket = io('https://0.0.0.0:8000');

socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected !', socket.connected);

    function capture() {
        canvas.width = 200;
        canvas.height = 200;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200, 200);
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

        return data;
    };

    var FPS = 22

    setInterval(() => {
        var imgData = capture();

        socket.emit('image', imgData);

    }, 1000 / FPS);
});
```

In Flask you can do

```
@socketio.on('image')
def image(data_image):
    encoded_image = data_image.split(",")[1]

    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded_image)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(decoded, np.uint8), -1)

return render_template ('#') #whatever you need to return after getting the socket data
```

Comment: hmm, i want to return the frame. but when i tried, it return error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: that error is not coming from Flask or JavaScript, it probably has to do with NumPy arrays